# Swift: Is there any difference in defining a function parameter with '!'

Tags: swift, function, parameters, option-type

I sometimes see a function which accepts an object as a parameter which has '!' as suffix.
I know it means the parameter is an implicitly unwrapped optional.
But I don't know what is the difference between the two case. i.e. defining a parameter with '!' and without '!'.

```
class Cat {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func tame(cat: Cat) {
    print("Hi, \(cat.name)")
}

func tame2(cat: Cat!) {
    print("Hi, \(cat.name)")
}

let cat = Cat(name: "Jack")
tame(cat: cat)
tame2(cat: cat)
```

As a result there is no difference between the function tame and tame2.
If the parameter has a possibility of being nil, I should define the parameter as an optional right?

```
func tame3(cat: Cat?) {
    if let cat = cat {
        print("Hi, \(cat.name)")
    }
}
```

In which case should I define a function's parameter as implicitly unwrapped optional like **tame2**?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223120/in-swift-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-a-function-signature

Comment: Thank you Martin R. I had not found the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In which case should I define a function's parameter as implicitly unwrapped optional like `tame2`?

Short answer: **Never.**

> If the parameter has a possibility of being `nil`, I should define the parameter as an optional right?

Right.

---

Implicit unwrapped optionals are useful for properties which could not be initialized in an `init` method but are supposed to have always a value and for compatibility to bridge Objective-C API to Swift, nothing else.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.