# Why can't an @IBOutlet be assigned let instead of var in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm following a tutorial on Swift and I noticed that the author uses `var` instead of `let` when declaring an `@IBOutlet` variable.  So I became curious as to why I can't use `let` instead since an object's properties are still mutable even if the object is constant or is this not the case?

The error Xcode shows when using `let` is

> `@IBOutlet` attribute requires property to be mutable

but I'm confused because `questionLabel` is a `UILabel` object and not necessarily a property of an object.  Or is the `questionLabel` object a property of the current viewController?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet let questionLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Thank you in advance if I'm over analyzing.

Comment: Start by understanding the difference between `let` and `var`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift

Comment: for pretty much the same reason it is an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541993/iboutlets-and-ibactions-require-in-the-end

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `@IBOulet` marked properties are generally properties of a ViewController that are connected using the interface builder. The view you create in the interface builder has to actually connect the interface elements in it to the properties during your actual application runtime.

For that reason it firstly creates a new ViewController using *some* `init` without connecting any interface elements. They only get connected at a later stage. For the runtime to be able to hook the properties up to the view elements after the object creation has completed they cannot be constants, they have to be mutable. Because they do not have a value after the initializer has finished they have to be optionals. And to not make using the properties cumbersome afterwards they are implicitly unwrapped optionals, so that you do not have to write `label!.property` but `label.property` suffices.

That is why your code crashes as soon as you try to do something with an `IBOutlet` variable which you failed to connect and that is also the reason why you cannot use / change / manipulate those fields in the initializer.

Regarding your actual `var` / `let` confusion. Yes, the object itself that is referenced using `let` can be changed, e.g. the `text` of a `UILabel` BUT the actual object reference cannot be changed. That would mean that if you do not give the constant a specific value in the initializer it would forever remain `nil`.

Answer (score 7):

For the simple reason that it is not assigned during initialization (in the `initXXX` methods) but later, when the view is being loaded.

The compiler actually cannot be even sure that the variable is ever assigned because the view loading is comletely dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

In swift, all vars and lets can be thought of as properties.

A property is immutable (a constant) if it's declared with `let`. It's mutable (a variable) if it's declared using the `var` keyword. That is **the** defining difference between `let` and `var`.

Outlets must be mutable because their value does not get set until after the object is initialized. (The view controller gets initialized and it's outlets don't get loaded right away.)

Comment: I'm still going to work through the tutorial as I enjoy this conversation with everyone as well as yourself.  Before I move on, I must ask just for learning purposes...will I still need to create initializers for my viewController or will it be usable as is by having IBOutlet on the properties and IBAction on the methods?

Comment: You often don't need a custom initializer for your view controller subclass. Since the IBOutlet properties are declared as optionals they can be left as nil until the view loads.

Answer (score 2):

You are right `questionLabel` is an object of type `UILabel` but used as a property of your `class ViewController`. That's why you have `@IBOutlet attribute requires property to be mutable`. If you use `var` you are saying that a property is mutable. If you use `let` you are saying that the property is immutable.

Try to create questionLabel without `@IBOutlet`and see what's going on. Probably, you can put let in front.

Answer (score 1):

First the ViewController is created, then the view tree is built. That means that when the ViewController finished it's `init` these views don't exist yet. They will be added just before `viewDidLoad` by parsing the XML-like data of the storyboard or XIB.

I know that it's Apple's default way of doing things but I would always write my outlets like:

```
@IBOutlet let questionLabel: UILabel?
```

For the simple reason it's absolutely not proven this label will really exist at run time. For example when reusing ViewControllers over multiple screens, changing the layout after setting the connections and so on this outlet might not be set. If you would use the `questionLabel` defined as `UILabel!` and it would be `nil` your application will crash. I don't think applications in production should ever crash over something silly like that.

For real application safety the only way to know really for sure it exists is to build your UI's in code. But the ease of use of Storyboards for one off screens is really tempting, I still use them a lot.

Comment: 1. If you are accessing outlets before the outlets have been connected through the storyboard/xib then you have a bug in your code and it should crash. 2. If you are creating the label (or whatever UI component) via code, it shouldn't be marked as an outlet. And even if you do everything in code, it still should be declared with `!` and not `?` because my first point still applies.

Comment: Interesting, I like the idea of this approach because it seems to be a safer way of doing things.  Can I ask, how do you keep track of how the interface should look and function as you do it programmatically?  Are you using a sketchbook, zeplin, whiteboard, or what's your process like?

Comment: Have to downvote because this is exactly the wrong approach. Firstly applications in production should crash if you as the programmer did something wrong. And they should crash as soon as possible: fail-fast / fail early. Treating every outlet as an actual optional will yield completely unreadable and useless code. Interface elements **have** to be present during the run. Using code to generate UI on the fly is even worse imho, but that is arguable, the first argument is not.

Comment: @rmaddy  if you rather like to see things crash as a developer or tester so you know something's wrong early I can certainly understand. That's what assertion errors are for. But your clients are not testers and your AppStore zero stars reviews are not JIRA. If your application crashes in production because something stupid like making the line pink instead of blue crashes in some kind of scenario you didn't test you're not helping your customers nor your product. You are not infallible nor your testers.

Comment: @Q.A.Neuro.Tech honestly I usually just write the code, run it a few times to adjust. But I know from experience that certain things need to be 8px or 20px to look good. I think there is software that actually creates the code for you like Paintcode but I never used it.

Comment: @DepartamentoB An outlet that is not connected when it should be is an error. Even if your app does not crash, it will not behave correctly. Using `!` is exactly the assertion you are looking for. I have used the same approach for 3 years now and no crash ever got to production or even to testers. The reason being that simply opening the screen (which I do many times in development) would make the app crash.

Comment: Recently it happened to me that somebody merged changes to a xib and some outlets were no longer connected. With `?` I wouldn't notice easily.

Comment: @Sulthan so to make your life as a developer easier every mistake you do ship leads to a crashing application for your end users? Every time I've seen an error like that ship it was always something trivial that would maybe just a minor annoyance if it wouldn't have taken the whole app down instead. Honestly I think this comes from the Real Programmers syndrome, or maybe writing a `guard` statement with an `assertionFailure` and an proper exception logging seems like a ton of work for every `@IBOutlet ` check you need to do. But shipping crashes has nothing to do with professionalism.

Comment: I do not ship apps with crashes which is something you are trying to imply here.

Comment: I think there are simply different philosophies no right or wrong, nothing that would warrant a ton of down votes because the answer was leading innocent users into dark woods. But don't forget to think about me as soon as you do ship your Very First Bug! :)