# Meaning of exclamation mark in optional identifier in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

I know with exclamation mark I can unwrap an optional value, means  I can convert optional type to a 'normal' type. But what about using exclamation in type identifier? I.e.

`@IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton!`

Why do I need `!`? Without `!` it means `back` can not take a nil value, isn't it? As `Int i` means neither `i` can take a nil value. But then why I need `!` in type identifier?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24583157/2592349

Comment: This question is a duplicate... but for the record, generally speaking **YOU** shouldn't use the `!`.  Typically just use it when Xcode is generating code or autocompleting it in for you.

Comment: Consider the case of an object that may have nil properties while it's being constructed and configured, but is immutable and non-nil afterwards (NSImage is often treated this way, though in its case it's still useful to mutate sometimes). Implicitly unwrapped optionals would clean up its code a good deal, with relatively low loss of safety (as long as the one guarantee held, it would be safe). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IBOutlet types need to be optional, otherwise the compiler would complain that the
variables aren’t set in all initializers. Swift doesn’t “know” that Interface Builder is
supplying the views at run time; therefore it would do its job and raise a build error
about the unsupplied values.

Comment: Can I mark variables like this that are initialised in viewDidLoad, but not in init method?

Comment: yes but the use of implicit unwrapped optional (!) is very dangerous if improperly used, it will generate runtime exceptions if you try to use variables that haven't been initialized. Hope it helps.