# Why does SwiftyJSON create implicitly unwrapped optional for its constants?

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping

In [SwiftlyJSON's code](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift), it defines the following constants using forced unwrapping:

```
///Error code
public let ErrorUnsupportedType: Int! = 999
public let ErrorIndexOutOfBounds: Int! = 900
public let ErrorWrongType: Int! = 901
public let ErrorNotExist: Int! = 500
```

What's the purpose of declaring constants as implicitly unwrapped optional here?

Note: I am not asking why or when to use implicitly unwrapped, but rather why it's used in SwiftyJSON as I see no reason for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why create "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I have seen this post before asking this.  I am asking why the constant needs to be declared this way in SwiftyJSON.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based.  While user might be capable of adding commentary about why or why not you should do this in the general case, you're asking about a specific case from a specific library.  Unless the SwiftyJSON author's stop by and offer a hand-of-God answer, any other answer can be nothing but pure conjecture.

Comment: Learning from other's code is a legitimate activity of coding and learning, and asking a question on why certain things are done in a certain way is valuable. Over-zealous generalization that any question of this nature can only generate answer of pure conjecture is not only incorrect (and who is to say conjecture has no value?), it dissuades good questions from being asked.  I urge you to re-examine your belief and the damage it will do to SO community.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe I'm wrong, of course better way is to ask author of the code. But here is my suggestions anyway:

1. By blaming commit we can see that changes where made at **Oct 6 2014** and as we know that Swift just released there could be some compiler warnings or maybe errors:

[image]

2. Actually by writing `Int!` instead of `Int` we are forcing compiler to generate `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>` type (and by knowing this fact we could return to item 1):

   ```
   public let x: Int  = 1
   public let y: Int! = 2

   println(x.dynamicType)
   println(y.dynamicType)
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   Swift.Int
   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.Int>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for investigating - what kind of compiler warning do you think necessitates this.