# Swift: Why do I need to unwrap non optional variable in declaration

Tags: swift, syntax, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I can't understand why I need to "force unwrap" variable type in it's declaration in my tests.

Let me give you an example to be more clear:

```
class testSomething: XCTestCase {

  var mockService: MockService!

  override func setUp() {
    mockService = MockService()
  }
  ...
```

So the goal obviously is to create a fresh instance of the mock service every time I run the test. I just don't understand why I need to declare this variable as `MockService!` type. What does the exclamation point after type really mean in this context?

Just to be clear, when I declare `mockService: MockService` Xcode complains that my test class does not have initializers

Comment: In this case: `mockService` is not initialized in place nor in the constructor, try to comment out the `!`. And take a look at this (second answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals here is a great overview of the use cases of `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`s.

Comment: `var mockService: MockService!` declares a variable with the type `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<MockService>`. It does not *"force unwrap variable type in it's declaration"*. – I would consider this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals.

Comment: yes, i didn't know the term `implicitly unwrapped optional`
@DánielNagy, can you please post your comment as a reply and I will mark it as a best reply.

Answer (score 1):

A non-optional variable **must** be initialized in the declaration line

```
var mockService = MockService()
```

or in an `init()` method

```
var mockService : MockService

init() {
  mockService = MockService()
}
```

If this is not possible declare the variable as forced unwrapped and make sure that the variable is not `nil` whenever it's used. Then it behaves like a non-optional.