# Swift Instance Member Issue

Tags: ios, swift, videocore

I'm trying to set up a variable at the top of a class file so I can use it a few lines down. The issue that I'm having is `Instance member 'streamWidth' cannot be used on type 'BroadcastViewController'`. So I think this is happening because I cannot reference this variable in the main class, I have to use it in a function. Now if this is the case, is there a way I could get around this?

```
 class BroadcastViewController: UIViewController, VCSessionDelegate {
      @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
      @IBOutlet weak var btnConnect: UIButton!

      var streamWidth:Int = Int(5)

      var session:VCSimpleSession = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: streamWidth, height: 720), frameRate: 30, bitrate: 1000000, useInterfaceOrientation: false)

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           previewView.addSubview(session.previewView)
           session.previewView.frame = previewView.bounds
           session.delegate = self

      }

      deinit {
           btnConnect = nil
           previewView = nil
           session.delegate = nil;
      }

      @IBAction func btnConnectTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
           switch session.rtmpSessionState {
           case .None, .PreviewStarted, .Ended, .Error:
                session.startRtmpSessionWithURL("rtmp://east-us.livewx.tv/live", andStreamKey: "fb4843e86976e37" + "?key=" + "e5615d9b171384a0613f")
           default:
                session.endRtmpSession()
           break
       }
       func connectionStatusChanged(sessionState: VCSessionState) {
            switch session.rtmpSessionState {
            case .Starting:
                 btnConnect.setTitle("Connecting", forState: .Normal)
            case .Started:
                 btnConnect.setTitle("Disconnect", forState: .Normal)
            default:
                 btnConnect.setTitle("Connect", forState: .Normal)
            }
      }

      // more functions left out for length reasoning

}
```

So some of these functions such as `deinit`, `btnConnectTouch`, and `connectionStatusChanged` all use the var session defined at the top.

What I'm asking: How would I go about using variables within the `var session:VCSimpleSession`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use instance variables when initializing other instance variables.

If I were you, I would change `session` to an [implicitly unwrapped optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals) and initialize it later:

```
  var session: VCSimpleSession!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       session = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: streamWidth, height: 720), frameRate: 30, bitrate: 1000000, useInterfaceOrientation: false)
       previewView.addSubview(session.previewView)
       session.previewView.frame = previewView.bounds
       session.delegate = self
  }
```

Comment: Wow, that did work - thanks! Question though, why are we doing this: `var session: VCSimpleSession!`?

Comment: That's called an implicitly unwrapped optional. Take a look at the link above and Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334