# What does force unwrapped mean in an expected argument type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Here is my line of code in Swift, it calls a method:

```
networkManager.postUserProfile(self, onSuccess: {(username: String, userID: NSNumber, recommendedLessons: [AnyObject]) -> Void in
    ... code block
}, onFailure: {(error: NSError) -> Void in
    ... another code block
})
```

The `networkManager` class is from Objective-C and is:

```
- (void)postUserProfile:(Profile *)profile
              onSuccess:(void(^)(NSString *username, NSNumber *userID, NSArray *recommendedLessons))successBlock
              onFailure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;
```

And the error message is:

> error: cannot convert value of type `(String, NSNumber, [AnyObject]) -> Void` to expected argument type `((String!, NSNumber!, [AnyObject]!) -> Void)!`

When calling a method, I understand that the `!` operator will force-unwrap an optional. However in this situation, what is the meaning of the `!` in the expected argument type?

Comment: FYI, of course, adding the exclamation points and parenthesis into the calling function did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many excellent existing answers ([such as these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)) explaining what implicitly unwrapped optionals are and why they are used, so I won't go into that.

Object pointer types in Objective-C header files are treated as implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift because the compiler doesn't know if nil is a valid value.

Your code should compile if you add an exclamation mark after each of the types in the block you are passing to `postUserProfile`:

```
networkManager.postUserProfile(self, onSuccess: { (username: String!, userID: NSNumber!, recommendedLessons: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    ... code block
}, onFailure: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
    ... another code block
})
```

However, a better solution is to add [nullability annotations](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) to your Objective-C header file.  The properties you mark nullable will be regular optionals and the rest will be non-optionals.

Comment: Thanks! The nullability annotations will make this a lot easier.