# What is the difference between 2 strings initialization in Swift `=String()` and `: String!`

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

String 1:

```
var string1=String()
```

String 2:

```
var editTag: String!
```

Comment: @SohilR.Memon This isn't exactly the same question - so, no duplicate.

Comment: you can follow this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Answer (score 4):

The top one declares and creates an instance of `String`.

The bottom declares an implicitly-unwrapped optional variable which can hold a `String` but doesn't create an instance of `String`.

Because the bottom is an optional it has a value of `nil` until it contains an instance of the class. By implicitly unwrapping it with a `!` you make a promise that it will  be filled with an instance, usually in the init function or similar. Because of this there's no need to check if it's filled or unwrap it before using it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that the second form also _defines_ an optional value which is initialized to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line declares a string variable and initialises it with an empty string.

The second line also declares a string variable but in this case it is an implicitly unwrapped variable. At this point the variable is not actually initialised and any attempt to access it would produce an "unexpectedly found nil" exception.

Declaring a variable in this way allows you to not initialise the variable in the initialiser function (which normally you would have to do). You might use this when you are going to initialise a variable in a function such as `viewDidLoad` or provide a value from another view controller's `prepareForSegue` method.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will create a n instance for string, like alloc init in objective c. 
The second one will declare unwrapped version of string but there will be no instance of this string and accessing this variable when there is no value in this string ,it will crash.