# What is the difference between optional and implicitly unwrapped optional?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Consider these two declarations:

```
var implicitUnwrappedOptionalInt: Int! = nil

var optionalInt: Int? = nil
```

The result would be `nil` in both the cases. So what is the difference?

Comment: This similar question will suffice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Answer (score 0):

An implicitly unwrapped optional can be (will be) initialized `nil` **BUT** you are telling the compiler that it will be set to a value before you first use it. If you do try and use it before it is initialized like I do below, you will crash everytime.

[image]