# Swifter way to check optional and then type

Tags: types, swift3, option-type

in Swift3 I had code like this

```
var result: String = ""
...
result = try db?.scalar(q) as! String
```

of course that's crap and often crashes.

1) the whole thing can be nil

2) since it's an optional binding, it may not be a String

This works pretty reliably

```
if let sc = try db?.scalar(q) {
    print("good news, that is not nil!")
    if sc is String {
        print("good news, it is a String!")
        result = sc as! String
    } else {
        print("bizarrely, it was not a String. but at least we didn't crash")
        result = ""
    }
else {
    print ("the whole thing is NIL!  wth.")
    result = ""
}
```

(Unless I forgot something.)

But it seems very nonswifty and long.  Is there a better way?  If not better, shorter?

Comment: BTW, it's probably best to unwrap your `db` early on in a `guard let` statement, handle the `nil` case, and then not have to worry about the chance of it being `nil` in the rest of the code

Comment: funny you mention that.  since it's a `var db:Connection?` (in a globally-accessed class), that in SQLite.swift, I don't know how to make it a non-optional type - because I don't know how to set it to some sort of default (like "0") when that class is initialized.  and the SQLite.swift code that initializes the database (ie "db". that `Connection`) does not run immediately. so the damn thing has to be optional everywhere it appears in the whole app.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an optional of it's initialized either inline (which can be a constant expression, as you said, or the result of running a closure), or if it's initialized in the class' initializer.

Comment: Usually you you should try to structure your app to avoid that, whenever possible. Otherwise, I would use an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: var db: Connection!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131092/discussion-between-alexander-and-joe-blow).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. I've moved this comment section to chat.

Comment: I made a related question to clarify this issue, thanks for raising it @Alexander !  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41251580/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let sc = try db?.scalar(q) as? String { ...
    print("good news, that is not nil!")
    print("good news, it is a String!")
    result = sc
else {
    print("bizarrely, it was not a String. but at least we didn't crash")
    result = ""
}
```

If all you're trying to get is the `String` value (if non-nil, and correctly types as `String`) or `""`, just do:

```
let result = try db?.scalar(q) as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: wait my friend - does that handle the case of the WHOLE THING being nil?  The whole binding can be optional.  This >>db?.scalar(q)<< is an optional binding; it can be nil.

Comment: Yeah, the nil propagates forward, because using `as? String`  on `nil` gives `nil`

Comment: Fantastic.  understood.  I guess that's the canonical answer cheers :)