# What is the simplest way to instantiate a new Codable object in Swift?

Tags: swift, codable

I have a Codable class:

```
class Task: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

When I try to instantiate it:

```
let newTask = Task()
allTasks.append(newTask)
```

It gives me error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call

All I want is to insert a new object (newTask) into an array. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: why do u want to use codable if you are not using any coding keys ??

Comment: My answer has been upvoted more than your question. Please consider accepting it, or explain why you will not accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

You can inherit the initializer from NSObject:

```
class Task: NSObject, Codable {
    var name: String = ""
}

let newTask = Task()
```

If you don't want to inherit NSObject, then just create your own initializer:

```
class Task: Codable {
    var name: String?

    init() {

    }
}
```

If you don't want to make `name` optional (or set it to a default), it has to be initialized in init() such as:

```
class Task: Codable {
    var name: String

    init(withName name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
let newTask = Task(withName: "ikevin8me")
```

Comment: OK, please see the edited response. The `name` var needs a default value. Otherwise, it is uninitiated before self is allocated.

Comment: OK, that makes it work but this is a really not the best solution. It needlessly brings in `NSObject` and all of the Objective-C baggage with it. And defaulting the `name` to the empty string is very non-Swifty.

Comment: Then write your own initializer.

Comment: I added an example without inheriting NSObject.

Comment: If you don't want an empty string, you can make the string optional or you have to initialize it to something in init(). I changed the second example to make it optional.

Comment: By the way, your question is what is the *simplest* way to instantiate a `Codeable` object, and I believe my first example is just that - its arguably the simplest answer here and you can, of course, change the `name` var to an optional if you don't like having it preset.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution is to use `struct`

```
struct Task: Codable {
    var name: String
}

let task = Task(name: "myname")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Task` class doesn't provide its own initializer so it gets the one defined in the `Codable` protocol (which it gets from the `Decodable` protocol).

Either add your own explicit `init` that takes a `name` parameter or change your class to a struct. Either way, you need to create a `Task` by passing in a name value so the `name` property can be initialized.

None of this addresses the fact that the code you posted makes no use of `Codable` so maybe there is no need for your class (or struct) to conform to `Codable`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Task` class doesn't provide any initializer to initialize an object that's why it's taking initializer from `Codable` protocol, Provide your own initializer to initialize an object.

Usage:

1.With Class

```
class Task: Codable {
    var name: String
    init(_ name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var task = Task("Jarvis")
```

2.With struct:

```
struct Task: Codable {
    var name: String
}

let task = Task(name: "jarvis")
```

Comment: Why did you make the `name` property implicitly unwrapped? Don't do that needlessly.

Comment: @rmaddy I am hoping it will be initialized properly.

Comment: Updated... Can you tell why you are so afraid of '!' ;)

Comment: I'm not afraid of it. I'm pointing out to you that you should not use it when it isn't appropriate. There's no need for it here.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger There are [a few very specific situations where you should use implicitly unwrapped optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals-since-that-implies-you-know-theres?rq=1). Most of the time, either it's unnecessary or it risks crashing your app, which seems like a reasonable thing to be "afraid" of.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yup...That's the beauty of stack overflow. we learn collaborating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not assign a default value to the property but implement the expected init method and a convenience variant that didn't take any arguments or alternatively have a factory method that creates an "empty" Task

Here is the code with both options

```
class Task: Codable {
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init("")
    }

    static func emptyTask() -> Task {
        return Task("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a object from json (for example when you use an API) like this:

```
struct Person: Codable {
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var age: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case age = "age"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
}

init(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let userDecoded = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)
        
        self = userDecoded
    }
    catch {
        age = 0
        firstName = ""
        lastName = ""
    }
}

func fullName() -> String {
    return "\(self.firstName) \(self.lastName)"
}
```

}

Comment: An example to test:

let json = """
    {
        "first_name": "C",
        "last_name": "Tangana",
        "age": 26
    }
"""

let data = Data(json.utf8)

let person = Person(data: data)
print(person.fullName())